# Differential content draft saving in web app

Tags: javascript, algorithm, web-applications, diff

I've seen that [Medium.com](http://www.medium.com) as well as [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) docs/sheets/etc. all use draft content saving so your editing doesn't get lost. Well Google's version is used for content versioning, but that's just an additional side effect as they're apparently not updating the same content but rather saving all of them getting content history records.

**I'm interested in the way these two internally work.**

If you observe Ajax calls being exchanged between the client and server one can see that both of them send some sort of partial content or user action saves. These kind of draft saving is very quick because even lengthy content can utilize tiny requests making draft saving a quick process. The problem is of course because these partial saves are now stateful, so they heavily rely on existing content state.

I'm also working on a web app that would benefit from such feature of tiny and quick saves, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel and jumping over all the hurdles. I'm not sure whether I should be

1. recording keystrokes and send them immediately which would then have to be *replayed* on the server to actually generate matching content state there.
2. should it work in any other way like recording keystrokes and sending them in predefined intervals?
3. not recording keystrokes at all but rather calculating content diffs in some way. Content diffs are done in CVSs like GitHub and I suppose this algorithm is very well defined by now and correctly shows removed as well as added content. If this process is not too complex for client-side processing I may go down this route and send small diffs

These are just three ways from the top of my head (although the first two are similar in nature) but there may be others that I haven't thought about.

I'm sure some of you may have done this before and have some experience as well as pros and cons of different techniques and if there's maybe an existing open source lib that can help simplify this without doing it all from scratch.

**How should this be done?**